# Suppress the Office 365 "Sign in to set up office" dialog?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I'm putting together a new image, and looking for a way to suppress showing the "Sign in to set up Office" licensing nag screen on Office 365 Build 1808 and newer. This dialog appears when an Office product is first opened, and can be dismissed by the user, but reappears on subsequent runs until the product has been licensed.

I've looked through the policies provided by the GPO pack for Office, and played around with some registry keys from prior Office versions, but nothing has stuck. Any ideas?

[image: O365 Licensing Nag Dialog]